# php if statement to match text to row value from mysql

Tags: php, if-statement

I've created a form so users can change their password, for some added security I want users to enter their old password before they can change it to the new one. I am having an issue with a simple if statement.

```
if ($row['password'] = $old_encrypt)
```

the password is md5 encrpyted, so I run the user inputted password through md5 before getting to this if statement.

What I want to check is that the user inputted password is equal to the one stored in the database. The above code however will accept any value as equal to the one stored in the db...thus can someone enlighten me to what the issue may be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To compare you need `==` or `===` (more is better). `=` is an assignment the truthness of which depends on the value being assigned.

Comment: 1 equals will assign $old_encrypt to $row['password']

Comment: Might be better to do this in the SQL -- only get rows where the name AND password match, and then see any rows are returned.

Comment: I always use MySQL to compare rows for login and chaning passwords,
`SELECT * FROM WHERE Username = '$Username' && Password = '$Password'`. Also, try to use parameterized query to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Well, then, I'm using FIVE ===== from now on!

Comment: @Blazemonger - _my_ comparison operators go to 11!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the assignment operator `=`. You'll have to use the comparison operator `==`, or even better the strict comparison operator `===`

```
if ($row['password'] === $old_encrypt)
```

Comment: The difference between the comparison and strict comparison method is that the latter checks if the two are identical. So type checking is done as well. In this case '2' won't match 2 because one is string and the other is integer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an assignment operator `=` instead of a comparison operator `==` or `===`.

Using an assignment operator inside of an `if` will usually evaluate to true, unless a 'falsey' value is being assigned.  An assignment operator can also cause an error if you have a constant or literal value on the right had side:

```
if(true = $variable)
    // will cause an error
```

however,

```
if($variable = true)
   // will always be true
```

Doesn't matter if $varibale was `true`, `false`, `72.3` or `'sunshine'` it is `true` now

Comment: An assignment operator returns the value that has been assigned. So if you're assigning anything that's falsish (0, boolean false), it will return false.

Comment: @andrewsi, thanks!  I guess I always realized this, but had never thought it through.